# Having errors when trying to extend a class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Alice alice = new Alice( "Alice"," The Red Queen", 180);
  Chesire chesire = new Chesire( "Chesire"," Jabberwocky", 150, true);
  Hatter hatter = new Hatter( "Hatter"," Jabberwocky", 200);

  ArrayList<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
      cookies=cookies;
      cookies.add("Eat me");
      cookies.add("Try me");

      try{
        int x = 0;
        int y = 10;
        int z = y/x;
      }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Example of exception");
      }
      finally{
        System.out.println("Who will win the battle? The white queen or the red! Lets play shall we?");
      }

      Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Choose a number, has to be between 1-7. Whoever is strong enough to make it to the end wins the war!");

      int aliceInWonderland = choice.nextInt();
      while(aliceInWonderland != 0){

        switch(aliceInWonderland) {
          case 1: alice.hitByRedqueen();
            break;
          case 2: hatter.hitByJabberwocky();
            break;
          case 3: chesire.hitByJabberwocky();
            break;
          case 4: chesire.heal();
            break;
          case 5: hatter.heal();
            break;
          case 6: alice.heal();
           break;
          case 7: alice.eatCookies();
            break;
          default: System.out.println("To begin you have to select between 1-7");
            
        }
        System.out.println("Want to play again? Just pick a number between 1-7 again!");
      }
    }
}
```

Having errors trying to extend a class in one of my seperate classes. I need to be able to extend a class as part of the project and I thought I've done it correctly but i keep getting errors.

Alice Class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Alice implements Heal{

  private int health;
  private String name;
  private String weapon;
  private ArrayList<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
  
  public Alice(String name,String weapon, int health){
    this.name=name;
    this.weapon=weapon;
    this.health=health;
    this.cookies=cookies;

    cookies.add("Eat me");
    cookies.add("Try me");
  }

  Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
  public void eatCookie(ArrayList<String> cookies){
    System.out.println("Alice has a choice between two cookies! Which cookie should she try 1 or 2?");
    int choiceCookie = a.nextInt();
  switch(choiceCookie){
    case 1: System.out.println(" Wow you made a good call! The eat me cookie made you grow into a GIANT. This will definetly help in your fight against the red queen. Health goes up by 50! New Status:" + (this.health+=50));
      break;
    case 2: System.out.println("OH NO! The try me cookie was a mistake, it made you shrink almost rendering you useless for battle! Health goes down 60 points. New Status: " + (this.health-=80));
     break;
      default: System.out.println("We only have two cookies to choose from, make a good choice!");
  }
  }
  public void hitByRedqueen(){
    this.health-=20;
    if(this.health<=0){
      this.health=0;
    }
    System.out.println("Oh man! + getName() +  got hit by the  the Red Queen and loses 30 points from health. New status:" + this.health);
    if(this.health==0){
      System.out.println(getName() + "is too weak to keep fighting, without her the fight against the red queen is over. THE BLOODY RED QUEEN HAS WON!");
    }
    
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getWeapon(String weapon){
    return weapon;
  }
  public void setWeapon(String weapon){
    this.weapon=weapon;
  }
  public int getHealth(int health){
    return health;
  }
  public int setHealth(int health){
    return this.health = health;
  }  
  @Override
  public void heal(){
    this.health+=100;
    System.out.println(getName() + " realized her courage and imagination are in her favor against the queen! New status: " + this.health);
  }
public void eatCookies() {
}
}
```

Chesire Class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Chesire extends Hatter implements Heal {
  private int health;
  private boolean vanishing;

  public Chesire(String name, String weapon, int health, boolean vanishing){

    super(name,weapon,health);
    this.vanishing = vanishing;
    this.health = health;
  }
  @Override
  public void hitByJabberwocky(){
    if(vanishing){
      this.health-=20;
    if(this.health<=0) this.health=0;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
    }

   if(!vanishing){
     this.health-=50;
     if(this.health<=0) this.health=0;
     System.out.println(getName() + "was too weak to vanish before the next attack of the " + getWeapon() + ". Health went down by 50!" + this.health);
   }
    if(health==0){
      System.out.println(getName() + "is no longer in the fight against the red queen...");
    }
  }
}
```

Hatter Class

```
public class Hatter implements Heal {
  private String name;
  private String weapon;
  private int health;

  public Hatter(String name, String weapon, int health){
    this.name = name;
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.health = health;
  }
  public void hitByJabberwocky(){
    this.health-=25;
    if(this.health<=0){
      this.health=0;
    }
    System.out.println("OH NO, " + getName(name) +"got hurt by a " + getWeapon(weapon) + ". Health has lowered by 25. New status: " + this.health );
    if(this.health==0){
      System.out.println(getName(name) + " is no longer in the fight against the bloody red queen...");
  }
  }
    public String getName(String name){
      return name; 
    }
    public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
    }
    public String getWeapon(String weapon){
      return weapon;
    }
    public void setWeapon(String weapon){
      this.weapon = weapon;
    }
  public int getHealth(int health){
    return health;
    }
   public void setHealth(int health){
     this.health = health;
   }

  @Override
  public void heal(){
    this.health+=100;
    System.out.println(getName(name) + "found strength from Alice! New status: " + this.health);
  }
}
```

I was expecting the class Chesire to implement the Hatter class, and it does to a certain extent I believe but I am getting these errors which in turn isn't allowing me to run the code.

```
 javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -d . Alice.java Chesire.java Hatter.java Heal.java Main.java
Chesire.java:17: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                         ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:17: error: method getWeapon in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                                                                                                                      ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -d . Alice.java Chesire.java Hatter.java Heal.java Main.java
Chesire.java:17: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                         ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:17: error: method getWeapon in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                                                                                                                      ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -d . Alice.java Chesire.java Hatter.java Heal.java Main.java
Chesire.java:2: error: Chesire is not abstract and does not override abstract method heal() in Heal
public class Chesire implements Heal {
       ^
Chesire.java:8: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
    super(name,weapon,health);
    ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:12: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
Chesire.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                         ^
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: class Chesire
Chesire.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                                                    
 javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -d . Alice.java Chesire.java Hatter.java Heal.java Main.java
Chesire.java:17: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                         ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:17: error: method getWeapon in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName()+ "tried to vanish, but wasn't quite quick enough to miss the full swing of the " + getWeapon() + "! Health went down by 20! Status update: " + this.health);
                                                                                                                      ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:23: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
     System.out.println(getName() + "was too weak to vanish before the next attack of the " + getWeapon() + ". Health went down by 50!" + this.health);
                        ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:23: error: method getWeapon in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
     System.out.println(getName() + "was too weak to vanish before the next attack of the " + getWeapon() + ". Health went down by 50!" + this.health);
                                                                                              ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Chesire.java:26: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
      System.out.println(getName() + "is no longer in the fight against the red queen...");
                         ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
5 errors
exit status 1

```

Answer (score 0):

Your getters shouldn't have arguments: e.g.

```
public String getName(String name){
 return name; 
}
```

should just be

```
public String getName() {
  return name; 
}
```

and the same for your other `get` methods.

Comment: Hatter.java:16: error: method getName in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("OH NO, " + getName() +"got hurt by a " + getWeapon() + ". Health has lowered by 25. New status: " + this.health );
                                   ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Hatter.java:16: error: method getWeapon in class Hatter cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println("OH NO, " + getName() +"got hurt by a " + getWeapon() + ".

Comment: If i dont do it the way i have it then i get these errors for the hatter class

Comment: @Louis Wasserman is correct. Remove the parameter from the Hatter get...() methods, and don't call those getters with arguments. I just dumped your code into a project, ran it with the changes and no errors occur. But you have to revise your calls to ```choice.nextInt()```. As is, you enter an infinite loop. Set ```int aliceInWonderland = -1;``` prior to entering the ```while``` loop. Then the first statement in the loop should be ```aliceInWonderland = choice.nextInt();```. Also, provide a note on how to quit -- e.g., ("any other number to quit") ...

Comment: ... and set aliceInWonderland = 0 in the default case. Finally, the last statement in the main method should be ```choice.close();```.

Comment: Can you show your exact code after the modifications I suggest that cause that compile error?